# Send Mail not working in Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel-5.1

I have created one demo for sending mail.
I am sending mail in contact page it is working.
But When I use dynamic email for TO, then it is not working.

#### Not Working

```
Mail::send('emails.otp_mail_format',['otp'=>'123456'], 
function($message){ 
    $message->from('no-reply@example.com');
    $message->**to($uEmailAddress)**->subject('AccountVerification');
});
```

But Working below code

```
Mail::send('emails.otp_mail_format',['otp'=>'123456'], 
function($message){ 
    $message->from('no-reply@example.com');
    $message->**to('kanu@example.com')**->subject('AccountVerification');
});
```

---

> **to('example@gmail.com')** is working
>
> but   **to($uEmailAddress)** then it is not worked

.

Comment: Have you checked what value is in uEmailAddress at the time of that call?  And when you say 'Not Working' could you be a little more specific?

Comment: I have got the value.

Comment: would you mind sharing what it is?

Comment: I have created sendMail function and passed two param (email and otp), Like : public function sendMail($uEmailAddress = null,$otp=null)
 {            Mail::send('emails.otp_mail_format',['otp'=>'123456'], function($message){ $message->from('no-reply@example.com'); $message->to($uEmailAddress)->subject('Account Verification'); });                         }

Comment: Please Give any alternative

Comment: Show us the whole function and then we can understand it better.

Comment: Once again, what does 'not working' mean here? Are you getting an error? Is the email not arriving where you think it should?  What's happening?  Also please show the value of uEmailAddress

Comment: Yes, "Not working" means , getting an error.

Comment: What error message do you get???

Comment: I have found the solution and it is working file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Mail::send('emails.otp_mail_format', ['otp'=>$user_otp],
>   function($message) use **($uEmailAddress)** 
>   {
>     $message->to($uEmailAddress)->from('no-reply@exaple.com','App Name')->subject('MyApp:: Account Verification');
>                           });